# Position of tuple element in the list

Tags: python

I have list of tuples:

```
tuple_list = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g, h)]
```

How to get position of second element in tuple in second position of the list for example.

I need it because i want to change this list the way that every second element of tuple equals to first element from next tuple. Like this:

```
tuple_list = [(a, c), (c, e), (e, g), (g, h)]
```

Comment: Why don‘t you just index the tuples? tuple_list[1][1] for example.

Comment: It works exactly how you think. What doesn't work like you think is changing them. You may want to write a question that illustrates that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples have indexes same as lists, therefore you can just grab the `[0]` index of the following tuple in the list.  However, a catch is that tuples cannot be modified, therefore you must generate a new tuple for each assignment.

For example:

```
tuple_list = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g, h)]

for x in range(0, len(tuple_list) - 1): # Go until second to last tuple, because we don't need to modify last tuple
    tuple_list[x] = (tuple_list[x][0],tuple_list[x+1][0]) # Set tuple at current location to the first element of the current tuple and the first element of the next tuple
```

Will generate the desired result

Answer (score 2):

Just use `tuple_list[listindex][tupleindex]`, where `listindex` is the location within the list and `tupleindex` is the location within the tuple. For your example, do this:

```
loc = tuple_list[1][1]
```

Just be aware that tuples are immutable collections. If you want to change them, you should use lists instead. However, variables with a tuple value can still be reassigned to a new tuple. For example, this is legal:

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c')
x = (1, 2, 3)
```

but this is not:

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c')
x[0] = 1
```

See also: [TutorialsPoint tutorial on lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists_data_structure.htm) and [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples_data_structure.htm).

Answer (score 0):

tuples in python can be accessed like arrays, using the index of the element